# Nuxt / Apollo - Set Authorization Header

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, nuxtjs

I am trying to create a login functionality using [nuxtjs](https://nuxtjs.org/) with the nuxtjs [apollo-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module) and [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) in the backend using [apollo-server](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server). I would like to pass the token from the frontend (nuxtjs/apollo-client) to the backend (nodejs/apollo-server).

---

**Signin Function**

```
async signin () {
  const email = this.email
  const password = this.password
  try {
    const res = await this.$apollo.mutate({
      mutation: signIn,
      variables: {
        email,
        password
      }
    }).then(({ data }) => data && data.signIn)
    const token = res.token
    await this.$apolloHelpers.onLogin(token)
    this.$router.push('/')
  } catch (err) {
    // Error message
  }
}
```

**nuxtjs.config**

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
const token = Cookies.get('apollo-token')

apollo: {  
  clientConfigs: {
    httpEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql',
    httpLinkOptions: {
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'authorization': token ? token : '' // passing the token on this line fails it returns '' 
      }
    }
  }
},
```

**Cookie in Browser DevTools**
[image]

---

I am unable to pass the token to the authorization header. I also tried to do it using localStorage (`'authorization': (process.client) ? localStorage.getItem('token'`) : ' '`) but this does not seem to be possible because of the server side rendering.

The token is saved in a cookie called 'apollo-token'. However the Authoriation header in the format 'Bearer token' is not set. According to the apollo-client documentation this should be set automatically (https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module#authenticationtype-string-optional-default-bearer).
I would be very very thankful for any kind of help!

Answer (score 0):

i encountered the same issue ,
this is strange , after some time it started working automatically
my configurations was

```
httpEndpoint: process.env.GRAPHQL_URL,
httpLinkOptions: {
  credentials: 'same-origin'
},
watchLoading: '~/plugins/apollo-watch-loading-handler.js',
errorHandler: '~/plugins/apollo-error-handler.js',
wsEndpoint: null, // process.env.STRAPI_GRAPHQL_WS_URL,
tokenName: 'session-token',
authenticationType: 'Bearer',
// Enable Automatic Query persisting with Apollo Engine
persisting: false,
// Use websockets for everything (no HTTP)
// You need to pass a `wsEndpoint` for this to work
websocketsOnly: false
```

also you should wrap your configs in "default"

```
apollo: {  
 clientConfigs: {
  default : { 
    httpEndpoint: process.env.GRAPHQL_URL,
    httpLinkOptions: {
     credentials: 'same-origin'
    },
    watchLoading: '~/plugins/apollo-watch-loading-handler.js',
    errorHandler: '~/plugins/apollo-error-handler.js',
    wsEndpoint: null, // process.env.STRAPI_GRAPHQL_WS_URL,
    tokenName: 'session-token',
    authenticationType: 'Bearer',
    persisting: false,
    websocketsOnly: false 
  }
 }
},
```

if this doesn't work try

```
  // in default config object
  getAuth: () => token ? `Bearer ${token}`: '',
```

Please let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

```
autoImports: true,
    authType: 'Bearer',
    authHeader: 'Authorization',
    tokenStorage: 'cookie',
    proxyCookies: true,
    clients: {
        default: {
            httpEndpoint: `${process.env.APPLICANT_URL}/graphql`,
            tokenStorage: 'cookie',
            tokenName: "apollo:default.token",
            httpLinkOptions: {
                credentials: 'include'
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works on nuxt 3 using nuxt apollo package

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).